# Bing Maps, Finding Multiple Geocode Search Results (Did you mean: Functionality)

Tags: javascript, geocoding, bing-maps

hope all is well.

I am using Version 7.0.

This morning I was struggling with something I thought should be rather simple.  Providing alternative search results in a Store Locator scenario. (Just like here - http://www.bing.com/maps)

I make a geocode request to Bing Maps Rest service like so:

```
var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + encodeURI(searchString) + "&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallbackSearch&key=" + credentials;
```

This all works great! I can capture my result returned into my function and parse it just fine as long as the user has typed in a query which had a matching geocode.

```
function GeocodeCallbackSearch(result) {
    try
    {
        alert(result.resourceSets[0].resources.length);
        // When the user searches an address that isn't quite right, I notice that the 
        // Length of the result set is greater then 1.
        // I would like to get at these so I can provide the "Did you Know"
        // functionality.

        // This is where I am having problems accessing the other results
        for (var i =0; i < result.resourceSets[0].resources.length;i++)
        {
           alert (result.resourceSets[i].resources[i].name);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err.message)
    }
```

Error:  I keep getting result.resourceSets[i].resources[i].name is undefined.

I know they are buried in there some where because the length is sometimes greater than 1!
Am I mus-understanding that result.resourceSets[0].resources.length is the count of geocode results returned?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i =0; i < result.resourceSets[0].resources.length;i++)
{
   alert (result.**resourceSets[i]**.resources[i].name);
}
```

Easy fix, the bolded needed to be changed, ofcourse!

```
// This is where I am having problems accessing the other results
        for (var i =0; i < result.resourceSets[0].resources.length;i++)
        {
           alert (result**.resourceSets[0]**.resources[i].name);
        }
```